# Visual Micro automatically inserts a breakpoint when no breakpoints are present

Tags: visual-studio, arduino

I am using the Visual Micro extension for Microsoft Visual Studio, which allows me to debug my Arduino project (in opposed to the Sketch IDE).

For some strange reason, when no breakpoints are present, it automatically adds a breakpoint at the beginning of the `loop` function.

When running via the debugger, I can simply remove it and continue running.

However, I cannot do the same when running without a debugger (i.e., upon power-up), since breakpoints seem to be "embedded" into the code as additional code segments (though I'm not really sure how explain the fact that the debugger allows me to remove a breakpoint).

Here is an illustration of the problem:

[image]

Now, I've been able to work-around it by adding a piece of "dead code" with a breakpoint:

```
if (0)
{
    // insert a breakpoint here
}
```

But this feels kinda "clumsy".

I suppose that if there is a solution to this problem, then it lies somewhere in here:

[image]

But I have not able to find it, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!

It turns out that all I needed was to hover on top of the breakpoint and read the tooltip carefully:

[image]

As you can read on the bottom line of this tooltip, in order to switch off that automatically-generated breakpoint, we only need to disable the Visual Micro's *Tutorial Mode*:

[image]

And voilà - we're all done!